# Triggering JSON request from 'click' event in a selector box using Mootools

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, events, mootools

Im trying to trigger an asynchronous JSON request when I select an option from an HTML selector box using mootools.

I have the following form element:

```
<form method="post" id="sel">
 <select id = "_selecor_id" size=3>
   <option value = "value_a" id = "option_a">OptionA</option>
   <option value = "value_b" id = "option_b">OptionB</option>
 </select>
<p id="response"></p>
</form>
```

I'm using the following javascriipt/mootools to send a JSON request carrying the form info

```
window.addEvent('domready', function()
{

$('_selecor_id').addEvent('click', function(){

    new Request.JSON({
    url: "my_php_script.php",
    onSuccess: function(response)
    {
      $('response').set('html', response.params)
    }
  }).get($('sel'));
})
});
```

to the following php script

```
$result['params'] = $_GET;
echo json_encode($result);
```

However, I'm told in Chrome's developer tools 'cannot read property "params" of null'
I don't see why request should be 'null' here.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `.get($("sel"))` is void - you need to pass on the value, not the element. it also needs a store for the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey man the answer to your question is in the question itself.

Your triggering the event when you are clicking on the select when like you said "select an option"

Click on the select would be wrong, however so would click on an option with in the select what your looking for is the onChange event the code would be as follows:

**HTML**

```
// Notice no form tag needed unless you are serializing other items
<select id = "_selecor_id" size=3>
    <option value = "value_a" id = "option_a">OptionA</option>
    <option value = "value_b" id = "option_b">OptionB</option>
</select>
<p id="response"></p>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    $('_selecor_id').addEvent('change', function(){
        new Request.JSON({ // This must return a valid json object
            url: "my_php_script.php",
            data: {
                'value': this.get('value')
            }
            onSuccess: function(responseJSON, responseText){
                $('response').set('html',responseJSON.params);
            }
        }).send();
    })
});
```

**PHP**

```
$result['params'] = isset($_GET['value']) ? $_GET['value'] : 'Not Set';
echo json_encode($result);
```

The responseJson variable will now contain something like {"params":"value_b"}

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    $('_selecor_id').addEvent('click', function(){
        new Request.JSON({
            url: "my_php_script.php",
            onSuccess: function(response){
                $('response').set('html',(response || this.response || this.responseText || {params: ''}).params)
            }
        }).get($('sel'));
    })
});
```

Comment: Cool, didn't know you could do that